# Are there cases where the last operation succeeds but the istream/ostream goes fail()?

Tags: c++, io, iostream

I'm a new learner of C++. In my understanding, `fail()` indicates whether the **last** operation on the `istream`/`ostream` succeeded or not. For example, let `ifs` be an `ifstream` opened to some valid file:

```cpp
string s;
while (ifs >> s) {
    // 1. assume the reading was taken successfully
    //    and do something according to that
}
// 2. assume the reading was unsuccessful
//    and do something according to that
```

May I ask if it is possible that, in some (corner) cases, we arrive at `2.` while the reading was actually successfully taken?

If so, what we do at `2.` could be problematic. For example, if we have set `ifs.exceptions(ifs.exceptions() | ios_base::badbit);`, then we would (probably) have assumed that `ifs` is empty at `2.`.

---

I came up with this question when I was self-learning C++ using Stroustrup's book *Programming: Principle and Practice Using C++* (2nd ed.). In Chapter 11.7 of this book, the writers design a `Punct_stream` class that takes an `istream` as `source`, processes data extracted from the `source` and then put the processed data into a data member of type `istringstream` called `buffer` waiting to be inputted into the program. The writers design the `operator bool()` method as follows (Page 404):

```cpp
Punct_stream::operator bool()
{
    return !(source.fail() || source.bad()) && buffer.good();
}
```

Firstly, I think `!(source.fail() || source.bad())` should be equivalent to just checking `source` since `fail()` accounts for both `failbit` and `badbit`, and checking `source` is equivalent to checking `!fail()`.

What is more related to my question is that, by this design, `operator bool()` will first check if the `source` is in an error state, and if so, it won't even look at the `buffer`. But reading data from a `Punct_stream` into a `string` will be done as long as there is character in `buffer`. So, if the `buffer` is not empty and the `source` is `fail()` somehow, then reading from the `Punct_stream` into a `string` will actually succeed while the checking on the `Punct_stream` condition will be `false`.

I wonder if the implementation of the standard library `istream`s may behave in some similar way such that in some cases the reading is actually successfully taken but the condition is evaluated to `false`?

Answer (score 0):

All iostream input functions start by creating a `sentry` object which checks the `good` state of the stream.  If the state is not `good` (that is any of `badbit`, `eof` or `failbit` is set), then the sentry will set the `failbit` and return false, which will cause the input function to immediately return without reading anything, without modifying (or even checking) the streambuffer, and without writing anything into the destination of the input function.

So by definition, if the stream test in the `while` is false, it must have either been false or eof before (and nothing was read into the string `s`), or it failed to be able to read anything into the string and it set the state to false.  In either case, nothing was read into the string.